# App inside another App, having visibility issue when minimized

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to run a C# application exe (inside app), inside another C# app (base app), using the following code

```
ProcessStartInfo pc = new ProcessStartInfo("appPath.exe");
Process p = Process.Start(pc);
Thread.Sleep(500);
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);    //panel1 is where the app runs
MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 250, 250, true);  //to position in the center
pc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
```

The inside appas well as the base app, has **FormBorderStyle** as **None**. Hence I have the following codes on both the apps to perform Move, Minimize and Close functions.

**Close:**

```
this.Close();
```

**Minimize:**

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

**Move:**

MouseDown:

```
MoveWindow = true;
startLoc = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
```

MouseUp

```
MoveWindow = false;
```

MouseMove

```
if (MoveWindow)
{
  Point newLoc = PointToScreen(e.Location);
  Location = new Point(newLoc.X - this.startLoc.X, newLoc.Y - this.startLoc.Y);
}
```

Globals:

```
private bool MoveWindow = false;
private Point startLoc = new Point(0, 0);
```

Now the problem, all the functions are working smoothly. Inside app is starting up as it should in the specified panel of base app. But, if I use the Move functionalities of either of the apps, the inside app (appPath.exe) becomes invisible. It still runs in background as shown in Task Manager.

Comment: One solution or work around was to call the MoveWindow line again. 
MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 250, 250, true); This brings up the inside app in the starting position again.

Comment: When  you set the `.Location` property as a **stand-alone app**, it'll be with respect to the top left of the SCREEN. Once you change the parent to the other app, the Location property is now with respect to the top left of the new "parent container".  Since you're using PointToScreen, the calculated location is probably putting it too far to the right and/or down to be visible inside your Panel. Instead of explicitly setting a location, try allowing the form to be moved using code [like this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577141/move-window-without-border).